# Can't add to cart or acces admin on Magento installed on ip domain name

Tags: php, magento, cookies

I have a Magento installation for testing purposes on a server that can only be accessed via IP address. The problem is that I can't access the admin panel and I can't add to cart. I think it's a problem with cookie domain, set as the IP `X XX.XXX.XXX.XXX` and not as a domain name. Is it possible to run Magento with IP as site url?

**Edit**: The problem appears like this:

- in the admin panel, when I try to login, the page just refreshes with no error redirecting to the login form again. The user and password are ok, because if I change them, it says "wrong username or password"
- when I add a product to cart, the page refreshes, but the cart is empty

Comment: What error do you get? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Edited the question. Thank's for the input. I am new here.